# SQL: select exact max for repeating value that based on other repeating value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
Table with repeating data in each column
|  userid   |   code   |    date    |
|3          |  YYYYYY  | 2017-09-20 |
|3          |  YYYYYY  | 2017-09-21 |
|3          |  YYYYYY  | 2017-09-22 |
|1          |  XXXXXX  | 2017-09-22 |
|1          |  XXXXXX  | 2017-09-23 |
|3          |  XXXXXX  | 2017-09-23 |
|3          |  XXXXXX  | 2017-09-23 |
|2          |  ZZZZZZ  | 2017-09-23 |
|3          |  ZZZZZZ  | 2017-09-23 |
|1          |  ZZZZZZ  | 2017-09-24 |
```

I need to get MAX(date) for each 'code', and get 'userid' for this MAX(date) and 'code', with group by 'code'.

```
SELECT
t1.userid,
t1.code,
t1.date
FROM codes AS t1

INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
              userid,
              code,
              MAX(date) as maxdate
            FROM codes
            GROUP BY code
            ) AS t2
ON (t1.code = t2.code AND t1.date = t2.maxdate)
ORDER BY date
```

But, MAX(date) value should be based on userid.

If code has user 1 and 2 and 3 then max date should be based on user 3 codes.

If code has user 2 and 3 then max date should be based on user 3 codes.

If code has user 1 and 2 then max date should be based on user 2 codes.

If code has user 3 then max date should be based on user 3 codes.

If code has user 2 then max date should be based on user 2 codes.

If code has user 1 then max date should be based on user 1 codes.

Response shuld contain: code, userid, and MAX(date) based on 'userid' value with gpoup by 'code' (one row for each code)

How to add this select?
Thanks for any help)
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccb50/1/0)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t1.userid,
    t1.code,
    t1.date
    -- SOME OTHER ROWS FROM TABLE
    FROM 
      codes AS t1 
      -- JOIN TABLE WITH SEARСH ROWS
      INNER JOIN (
        -- BEGIN SELECT MAX LOGIC
        SELECT 
          code, 
          CASE WHEN max3date IS NOT NULL THEN max3date WHEN max2date IS NOT NULL THEN max2date ELSE max1date END AS maxdate
        FROM 
          (
            -- BEGIN SELECT MAX FOR EACH GROUP
            SELECT 
              all1.code, 
              u3.max3date, 
              u2.max2date, 
              u1.max1date 
            FROM 
              codes AS all1 
              LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT 
                  code,  
                  MAX(date) AS max3date 
                FROM 
                  codes 
                WHERE userid LIKE '3%' 
                GROUP BY 
                  code
              ) AS u3 ON (all1.code = u3.code)
              LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT 
                  code, 
                  MAX(date) AS max2date 
                FROM 
                  codes 
                WHERE userid LIKE '2%'
                GROUP BY 
                  code
              ) AS u2 ON (all1.code = u2.code) 
              LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT 
                  code,  
                  MAX(date) AS max1date  
                FROM 
                  codes 
                WHERE userid LIKE '1%' 
                GROUP BY 
                  code
              ) AS u1 ON (all1.code = u1.code) 
            GROUP BY 
              code
          ) t3
      ) AS t2 ON (
        t1.code = t2.code 
        AND t1.date = t2.maxdate
      )  
    ORDER BY 
      t1.date
```

It works fine for me on 24M rows. Date (time) should be unique. 
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9e1c3/5)

Answer (score 1):

Use ANSI-standard window functions:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by code
                                order by date desc, userid desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

Your SQL Fiddle uses MySQL which does not support window functions.  In that database, you can do:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM codes c
WHERE (c.userid, c.date) = (SELECT c2.userid, c2.date
                            FROM codes c2
                            WHERE c2.code = c.code 
                            ORDER BY c2.date DESC, c2.userid DESC
                            LIMIT 1
                           );
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccb50/6).

Note that you still get duplicates for `'XXXXXX'` because its maximum occurs multiple times in the data.

Comment: Thanks for reply, duplicate 'XXXXXX' that's not a problem. Problem is with last row - (1 - ZZZZZZ - 2017-09-24). I need to filter by userid. Data should be taken from user 3 -  (3 - ZZZZZZ - 2017-09-23).